# How to print another component when i logout. React and Firebase

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

How I can render another component when i logout on firebase.

I´m trying to re-render the page to print the LoginPage

This is my **LoginPage** that is render when I loggin with another form.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

/*Importing firebase*/
import firebase from "firebase";

/*Importing pages*/
import LoginPage from "../login/LoginPage";

/*Importing components*/
import Header from "./containers/HandleHeader";

class IndexPage extends Component {
  shouldComponentUpdate() {
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
      if (user) {
      } else {
        this.forceUpdate();
        return <LoginPage />;
      }
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Header />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default IndexPage;
```

And this is my handleLogout that work when I click my logout button.

```
handleLogout = e => {
    firebase
      .auth()
      .signOut()
      .then(() => this.forceUpdate());
  };
```

I want to make that when I logout I don´t need reload the page.

Answer (score 0):

Usually the best way to do this is to maintain the logged-in state somewhere, then protect the entry points to any components that require authentication with logic like this:

```
render() {
  const { loggedIn } = this.props;
  if (!loggedIn) return <Redirect to="/login" />;

  // Reset of component rendered below this point
}
```

Note that this logic can be in the component itself, some parent component, or some higher order component. The key is to have it somewhere that will prevent access to any protected component by redirecting in the render method before any protected information can be reached.

Redirecting is often achieved using some routing package like, say, [react-router-dom](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/quick-start), to navigate around. This means that when you log out, a user is implicitly always redirected because they can no longer access the protected components anymore.

Comment: Hmm but, I want to do it :/

Comment: How I can "reload" my page, but without recharging

Comment: One important thing to realize is that what I suggested doesn't reload the page in React. It sounds like you want to change the component rendered on the screen, and the method I suggested is a great way to do that. Even if you don't use a redirect, you can still simply track the logged-in state and render a different component when the user isn't logged in. So instead of <Redirect />, you can return something like <Login /> for your login page.

Comment: class HomePage extends Component {
  state = {
    email: ""
  };

  componentWillMount() {
    this.handleRenderPage();
  }

  handleRenderPage = () => {
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
      if (user != null) {
        this.setState({ email: user.email });
      }
    });
  };

  render() {
    return <div>{this.state.email ? <IndexPage /> : <LoginPage />}</div>;
  }
}

Comment: It looks like you're not setting the state back to null when the user logs out. I only see logic for when the user logs in. What about `else this.setState({ email: null });` in `this.handleRenderPage`?